# javascript and css files are encoded in nginx

Tags: nginx, http

I have a reverse proxy that returns only the javascript and css in some encoding. I do not know if it is encoded or just not decompressed.

This is wat the server returns: `���^style.css��;ks�:��;S��d�y�WMjIB2�3I`

this is what I expect: `*{margin:0;padding:0}`

My html loads in just fine it's only the css and js files. I already tried turning on/off gzip and brotli. I also tried `proxy_set_header Accept '*/*';` but that also did not help.

I can see in the developer tools that the response headers are: `Content-encoding: gzip` and `Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8`. and the request header `accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1`

I do see this `application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8` as Content-type for the javascripts.

when I directly access the server all files are served correclty. I don't know what the problem is or where too look at.